# Edit Experiment Name in Google Optimize

Tags: google-optimize

I am using Google Optimize - I have not yet started the experiment but I want to edit the name. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. In the DETAILS tab, on the right there is a sidebar-pane.

When you click the grey pencil behind 'Experiment information' there you can edit the experiment name.